# What is the origin of the trope of a school for magic/wizards/witches?

Tags: history-of

[Roke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea_(universe)#The_School_of_Magic), [Brakebills College for Magical Pedagogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magicians_(Grossman_novel)), [Wyverly College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabriel), [Shiz University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_(Maguire_novel)#Gillikin), others… Many fantasy authors have written of schools where magic is a central part of the curriculum.

**What work of fiction first presented a school where students primarily studied magic with some degree of description of school life and instruction there?**

Novels, traditional folk tales, comics, graphic novels as well as radio plays, and film or television are all acceptable.

Comment: "The Folklore of Discworld sees a forerunner of this trope in a first-century A.D. Roman account of the schooling of Celtic druids in remote groves and caves for twenty years on end, but notes that it only really flowered with the advent of universities proper during the middle ages. As soon as there were universities, rumors started about there being an evil counterpart, a "black school", where black magic was taught. Frequently actual institutions of learning — in foreign countries, and often associated with a different faith — were suspected of being "black schools"."

Comment: @DavidW thank you for not linking the TV tropes page :p

Comment: Please specify how your question differs from this one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18437/what-was-the-first-school-of-magic-mentioned-in-modern-fantasy-literature

Comment: I've read somewhere or other that in ~Shakespeare's time it was believed in Scotland that such a school existed in Padua.  (Why Padua? Why Scotland? Who knows?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Possibly the Romanian legend of the Scholomance.

There is a legend in Romania of a school called the Scholomance. Emily Gerard’s “Transylvanian Superstitions”, published in 1885, gives a description of the school, what is learned there, and how many students attend at a time.

> As I am on the subject of thunderstorms, I may as well here mention the Scholomance, or school supposed to exist somewhere in the heart of the mountains, and where all the secrets of nature, the language of animals, and all imaginable magic spells and charms are taught by the devil in person. Only ten scholars are admitted at a time, and when the course of learning has expired and nine of them are released to return to their homes, the tenth scholar is detained by the devil as payment, and mounted upon an Ismeju (dragon) he becomes henceforward the devil's aide-de-camp, and assists him in 'making the weather,' that is to say, preparing the thunderbolts. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Transylvanian Superstitions (Emily Gerard, 1885)](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/52165/52165-h/52165-h.htm)*</sup></sub>

The description in is short, and it doesn’t mention what everyday student life is for those in attendance, but it is a school of magic with some specific description of the subjects studied. The writing quoted above is in part what inspired Bram Stoker to write Dracula, and in it he said Dracula studied in the Scholomance, and learned how to become a vampire there.

> “The Draculas were, says Arminius, a great and noble race, though now and again were scions who were held by their coevals to have had dealings with the Evil One. They learned his secrets in the Scholomance, amongst the mountains over Lake Hermanstadt, where the devil claims the tenth scholar as his due.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Dracula (Bram Stoker)*</sup></sub>

So it is mentioned in a well-known novel as well.

#### It also may be the Cave of Salamanca.

It is also possible that the earliest legend of a magic school is the Cave of Salamanca in Salamanca, Spain. It is referenced in the poem below, published in 1805.

> “In these far climes it was my lot
>
> To meet the wondrous Michael Scott;
>
> A wizard of such dreaded fame
>
> That when, in Salamanca's cave,
>
> Him listed his magic wand to wave,
>
> The bells would ring in Notre Dame! 
> <sub><sup>*[- The Ride to Melrose (Sir Walter Scott)](https://rpo.library.utoronto.ca/content/ride-melrose)*</sup></sub>

It is mentioned more in-depth in Miguel de Cervantes’s “La Cueva de Salamanca”, published in 1615, but I was unable to find an English translation of it. Since I was unable to read it, I cannot tell how much details are given regarding what is studied there or descriptions of students’ experiences.